# how to over right catalog/category/view.phtml

Tags: category, layout, xml

I try to change the category page by overloading catalog/category/view.phtml.

In my module, I added in mymodule.xml :

```
<catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="category.info">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>mymodule/catalog/category/view.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>    
</catalog_category_view>
```

but it does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with category.products

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="category.products">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>mymodule/catalog/category/view.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>    
</catalog_category_view>
```

and make sure your module depends on `Mage_Catalog`.

If that does not work, try this.

```
<my_custom_handle>
    <reference name="category.products">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>mymodule/catalog/category/view.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>    
</my_custom_handle>
<catalog_category_layered>
    <update handle="my_custom_handle" />
</catalog_category_layered>
<catalog_category_default>
    <update handle="my_custom_handle" />
</catalog_category_default>
```